How do I calculate the current of non linear inductor L1 with multiple AC voltage source and 1 current source not connected directly to the circuit

I know I have to transform all the source into 1 equal source, but cannot figure out how to. Superposition clearly did not work with a non linear circuit. All the stats is in the picture.
Here is what I have tried: combine e1 and e2 into Ea and C1, L2, R2 and C2 into Za, L3 and R3 into Z3 
ps:L1 is a non-linear inductance. L1=0.1H is just a writing mistake

Can you please show your efforts and what you have tried so far?

I have combined all the RLC components and voltage source into 1 but cannot find any way to transform the current source

Two quick questions: a) how have you combined the other sources? Maybe if you show a schematic, we can help you better from there. b) Looks like $L_1$ is defined two times, once as a constant and once as a non-linear inductance. Could you clarify which one is to be used?

sorry my bad. L1=0.1H is just a writing mistake. I edited what I have tried with this problem. I cannot find any way to solve it further
